# Add a like button for a single facebook page timeline post on an external website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I'm trying to implement a Facebook page timeline in a website with the open graph API from Facebook:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{PAGEID}/posts?access_token={accessToken}&limit=5
```

This gives my a nice array of timeline objects. Per post I would like a like button for that specific single post. Does anyone know how to do this with PHP? I can't find any documentation about this 'like functionality' on the facebook developers site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the post id of the post you need and after that make a post request to 'https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/likes'
For further reading you can visit:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/publishing/
And for testing you can visit:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=POST